# aggregate columns across 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the `total service costs` in a specific year (think of procedures a dentist may do). I have a `service` table, which has the `serviceID and serviceCost`. In the `visit` table, I have the `date, visitID, and patientID` (I'm thinking to pull the date from this table, as the others don't make sense to pull date from). Another able is `completedservice`, so I have the `serviceID and visitID` (If the visit ID is 2000, and someone had multiple services done, it will list 2000 multiple times with different serviceIDs).

I *think* I understand what I need to do, but I'm thrown off. Any help is appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
Select s.serviceID, Count(s.serviceID)*s.serviceCost
From completedservice cs, service s, visit v
Where
  cs.serviceID = s.serviceID
  AND cs.visitID = v.visitID
  AND visitDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-31'
Group By s.serviceID;
```

**completedService Table:**

```
completedServiceID, serviceID, visitID
1   1   1
2   2   1
```

**service Table:**

```
serviceID, serviceCost
1            20
2            20
```

**visit Table:**

```
visitID    visitDate
1           2007-08-10
2           2007-08-12
```

Thank you for the guidance in helping me piece everything together.

Comment: Please begin to write the query. Give the results or errors that occur from your attempts.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Thank you for helping me with formatting! Still very new.

Comment: ^^ If you highlight your code and use the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctl-k`, it will be indented 4 spaces as a code block, which gets syntax highlighting. No need to surround code blocks with backticks, though those are useful for creating inline code.

Comment: Can you post an example of what output you are hoping to achieve given the input tables you posted? I have a suspicion that what you need is a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the implicit inner joins in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Can you give us an sqlfiddle?

Comment: is that visitDate or visitTime ...?

Comment: @user4035 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83d67/2

Comment: may we know the output you get, and in `completedService` the serviceID values are 50, 57 and not any of 1 or 2 from service table? is all that real or dummy data?

Comment: Thank you for giving user the sqlfiddle.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski In the question there is inconsistency: serviceID in is 50 and 57. While in the service table it is 1 and 2. I fixed it in the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5cbd/1

Comment: replace 50 with 1 and 57 with 2 in `completedService` and you get some result to see

Comment: @AmolPujari I fixed it in the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5cbd/1

Comment: The data I provided is two rows out of the 30k + rows I'm working with (sorry, it isn't dummy data [needed to double check])

Comment: were you not simply excited to post this question and not cross checking what you are dealing with carefully, step by step OR do you have some other query issue that you are trying to show using some dummy data?

Comment: What I posted is correct, the 50 and 57 and throwing people off because they are used later in the table. :)... Nope... that is the first two rows of 30k + like I said...

Comment: so query seems to be working, I assume you have visitDate indexed, and BETWEEN clause includes the boundary dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply number of visits by service cost for each service:

```
SELECT
    SUM(tbl.total_cost) AS total
FROM
(
SELECT 
    s.serviceID, 
    COUNT(s.serviceID)*s.serviceCost AS total_cost
FROM 
    completedservice cs, service s, visit v
WHERE
    cs.serviceID = s.serviceID 
AND 
    cs.visitID = v.visitID 
AND 
    visitDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-31'
GROUP BY
    s.serviceID
) AS tbl;
```

This assumes, that service cost doesn't change during period. If it changes, you need to do this procedure for each period.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9605e/5

Comment: @ITNovice15 Sum of what? Total sum of all the products?

Comment: Yeah, so it calculates the service costs of all serviceIDs for the year, but I need the total sum of all of the service costs for the year

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SUM(s.serviceCost)
From visit v
  Join completedservice cs on cs.visitID = v.visitID
    Join service s on s.serviceID = cs.serviceID
Where v.visitDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-31'
```

This query performs line by line:

```
Calculate total sum spent
during all visits
by finding all completed services on each visit
and finding details of each service (that was completed)
where visit date is in 2007
```